# Как определить позицию буквы в алфавите?

Tags: javascript

Даны буквы A, b, c, e. Как определить их позиции в алфавите?

Например, надо получить вместо a, b, c, e - 1, 2, 3, 5.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor а при чем тут отладка? У человека вполне себе простой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b','z', 'p'];
console.log(arr.map(letter => letter.charCodeAt(0) - 96))
```

Comment: Согласен с вами. Потом обычно задается вопрос про большие/маленькие буквы, про русский алфавит, и следом вопрос про букву Ё ))

Answer (score 0):

например так:

```
const alphabet = "абвгд";
const index = alphabet.indexOf('в');

if (index != -1)
    console.log(index + 1);
else
    console.log('не найдено');
```

Comment: они могут идти не по порядку

Comment: @asfd: Укажите это в вопросе - кнопка *Править* под вопросом.

Comment: вы алфавит задаёте сами - там все по порядку, а если вам надо просто найти в тексте - то тоже самое `indexOf`

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так?

```js
const alphabet = [ 'd', 'Y', 'A', 'b', 'c' , 'e', 'a']; 
const text = ['a','b','c','e'];

const result = text.map(item => alphabet.indexOf(item));

console.log(result);
```